# AP Calculus problem with $\sin x \over x$

Tags: calculus

I am working on a problem like this.

> $\frac{dy}{dx}= {\sin x \over x}$ and $f(1) = 2$.  Find the value of $f(2)$.

Initially I tried to integrate $\sin x \over x$, but later I learned that there is no elementary algebraic solution to this.

I have also thought about using the fundamental theorem of calculus that says

> $$\frac{dy}{dx} \int_a^x {\sin t \over t} dt={\sin x \over x}$$

I want to solve for $a$ that lets $f(1) = 2$, but I was not successful. Is there some other method to solve this or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a problem for which a calculator is needed?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Exactly what I was going to ask.

Comment: I would like to assume that it is not needed, but if it were okay could you explain me what to do? I tried to only to fail.

Comment: college board loves asking questions like this. Just remember the fundamental theorem of calculus: $\int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b) - F(a)$, where $F'(x) = f(x)$

Comment: You've written $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in two places but in other places you use $f$ for the unknown function. Are $y$ and $f$ the same?

Comment: @JiK In high-school calculus terminology, they are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$\int^2_1\dfrac{\sin x}{x}dx=f(2)-f(1)$$
If a calculator can be used, we can write this as
\begin{align}
f(2)&=f(1)+0.659\\
\implies f(2)&=2.659
\end{align}
However, if it isn't a calculator problem, consider using Euler's method with an appropriate number of subintervals.

Comment: Wow, that actually makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You actually need a calculator for this. We know that $$\Delta y=\int \frac{dy}{dx}dx$$ You have seen this in displacement, which is $\Delta y$. Also, should make sense since the $dx$'s cancel out. Hence,

$$f(2)=f(1)+\int_1^2 \frac{\sin x}{x}dx=2+0.6593\approx 2.6593$$